# Populate obseravble array in knockoutjs using typescript after data update

Tags: typescript

I am surviving issue on data-bind into the child model data to the html using typescript with knockout js.

the summary is the ko.observalbe and an array and under the summery there are personinfo array and inside personinfo there are details array.
so the details I get by the personid. and after getting each personid data I update into the

its updating summary arraylist model fine.
But the data not binded to the html in knockoutjs.

````
    var currentitems = JSON.stringify(response);
const summary = this.summary();          
var pindex = summary.findIndex((_) => _.personInfo().personId === personId);
 summary[pindex].personInfo().details = JSON.parse(currentitems);```

     
the summary is the ko.observalbe and an array and under the summery there are personinfo array and inside personinfo there are details array.
so the details I get by the personid. and after getting each personid data I update into 
its updating summary arraylist model fine.
But the data not binded to the html in knockoutjs.
>>>>>summary as data>>>>
 <table class="table mb-0 table-borderless table-sm">
                <thead class="table-primary">
                    <tr>
                        <!-- ko if: data.isAdmin -->
                        <th></th>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <th>ApptDate</th>
                        <th>ICD-10</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Provider</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- ko foreach: { data: data.personInfo.details, as: 'group', noChildContext: true }-->
                    <!-- ko foreach: { data: group.alerts, as: 'd', noChildContext: true }-->
                    <tr data-bind="css: { 'border-top': $index() === 0 }" class="align-middle ">
                        <!-- ko if: data.isAdmin &&  $index() === 0 -->
                        <td data-bind="attr: { rowspan: group.alerts.length }">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   data-bind="value: d.appointmentDate, checked: data.selectedDates"
                                   class="form-check-input" />
                        </td>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <td data-bind="date: d.appointmentDate" class="border-end"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: d.icdCode" class="border-end"></td>
                        <td class="border-end">
                            <!-- ko if: d.clientAgreeStatus === 2 -->
                            <abbr data-bind="text: d.clientAgreeStatusName,
                                                      attr: {title: d.clientComment}"
                                  data-toggle="tooltip"
                                  data-placement="right"></abbr>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: d.clientAgreeStatus === 2 -->
                            <span data-bind="text: d.clientAgreeStatusName"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="text: d.providerName" class="border-end"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: d.officeName" class="border-end"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
````